# Framework for algorithm

Tags: frameworks

I want to throw my self in Application de localisation and I wonder which algorithm to use, Are there any frameworks that implement A* or Dijkstra algorithm so as to facilitate development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest to get acquainted with the [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org).

This is a graph-based DB implementing A* and Dijkstra (along with others) path finding algorithms *out of the box*. You can communicate with this DB via REST (running as a Standalone Server) or embed DB into your app (there are several bindings for different languages — [Python](https://github.com/neo4j/python-embedded), [Ruby](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/) etc.).

You can read about built-in graph algorithms on [this](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html) page.

[image: Neo4j admin interface]